# jsonpatch adding element to array and creating it if not exist

Tags: json-patch

I'm trying to append an element to an array. But i cannot ensure that the array alread exists. So it should be created if not.

This example works:

Source json:

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Patch doc:

```
[{
  "op":"add",
  "path":"/data/-",
  "value": "foo"
}]
```

But in this case it will not append anything:

Source json:

```
{}
```

I tried a solution by adding first an empty array and then appending, but this will always clear existing entries:

```
[{
  "op":"add",
  "path":"/scores",
  "value": []
}, 
{
  "op":"add",
  "path":"/scores/-",
  "value": {
    "time":1512545873
    }
}]
```

Have i missed something or is there no solution for this in the spec?

Comment: Your patch is perfectly right. You can try it here: https://json8.github.io/patch/demos/apply/

Comment: Maybe my question is not detailed enough. My example is working but the result is not what i need.
This is a working example for adding one element to another: https://jsfiddle.net/s22ksqf8/ but this is not working if the source document is empty.
And if you use my second example (https://jsfiddle.net/67xLty9n/) only the added item will be in the result document

Comment: Oh I misread your question. You can't do this in a pure patch, you'll need some logic in your JS. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's nice to you see you using fast-json-patch. I maintain this lib.

I would say you can't acheive this by pure JSON patches. You'll need some logic in your JS. Like the following:

```js
var doc = {};

var patch = [{
  "op": "add",
  "path": "/scores/-",
  "value": {
    "time": 456
  }
}];

var arr = jsonpatch.getValueByPointer(doc, '/scores');
if (!arr) {
  jsonpatch.applyOperation(doc, {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/scores",
    "value": []
  });
}

var out = jsonpatch.applyPatch(doc, patch).newDocument;
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fast-json-patch/2.0.6/fast-json-patch.min.js"></script>

<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: ok is use a solution like this currently. I hoped there is a direct way to do this. But thanks for your reply

Comment: @Omar Alshaker I feel like this lib could help a lot of people with a little better documentation. Please add some, apart from that it's a really good package.

Answer (score -1):

At Openshift you can do this using command:

```
oc patch dc/NAME_OF_DC --type=json --patch '
[
  { 
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/-",
    "value": {
      "name": "KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE",
      "valueFrom": {
          "fieldRef": {
              "fieldPath": "metadata.namespace"
          }
      }
    }
  }
]
'
```

[More you can find here](https://gist.github.com/jovemfelix/f65d2b57938939098c4c8acdbe8b3f38)