# How to add init container with kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I want to add an initContainer to all of my pods (with a specific annotation) in my kustomize base. The newly added init container should be the first init container. My patch looks like this.

```
patches:
  - target:
      kind: Pod
      annotationSelector: "database_init=True"
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/initContainers/0
        value:
          name: database-init
          ...
```

This works fine for all pods that already have an init container. Unfortunately, I have pods without init containers and there the patch fails with the error `add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: \"/spec/initContainers/0\"`.
How do I write a patch that works for all my pods?

Complete example:

```
.
├── base
│   ├── kustomization.yaml
│   ├── pod-1.yaml
│   └── pod-2.yaml
└── overlay
    └── kustomization.yaml
```

```
# cat base/pod-1.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod-1
  annotations:
    database_init: True
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: something
      image: alpine:latest
      command: ["sleep", "10" ]
  containers:
    - name: main
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [ "sleep", "60" ]
```

```
# cat base/pod-2.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod-2
  annotations:
    database_init: True
spec:
#   initContainers:
#     - name: something
#       image: alpine:latest
#       command: ["sleep", "10" ]
  containers:
    - name: main
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [ "sleep", "60" ]
```

```
# cat base/kustomization.yaml
resources:
  - pod-1.yaml
  - pod-2.yaml
```

```
# cat overlay/kustomization.yaml
resources:
  - ../base

patches:

  - target:
      kind: Pod
      annotationSelector: "database_init=True"
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/initContainers/0
        value:
          name: database-init
          image: alpine:latest
          command: [ "sleep", 10 ]
```

Result:

```
$ kubectl kustomize overlay
error: add operation does not apply: doc is missing path: "/spec/initContainers/0": missing value
```

After uncommenting the init container of pod-2, everything works.

Edit: Added the annotationSelector.

Edit: Added the complete example code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSONPatch patches in general are fundamentally unable to handle the "append to existing list or create new list" situation. See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47670366/147356).

Fortunately, with Kustomize 5.0.1 it appears to be possible to achieve your goal using a strategic merge patch. Given your example configuration, if I place the following in `overlay/kustomization.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../base/

patches:
  - target:
      kind: Pod
      annotationSelector: database_init=True
    patch: |-
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata:
        name: __ignored__
      spec:
        initContainers:
          - name: database-init
            image: alpine:latest
            command:
              - init
              - the
              - database
```

Then running `kustomize build overlay` produces the following output:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    database_init: "True"
  name: mypod-1
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "60"
    image: alpine:latest
    name: main
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - init
    - the
    - database
    image: alpine:latest
    name: database-init
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "10"
    image: alpine:latest
    name: something
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    database_init: "True"
  name: mypod-2
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "60"
    image: alpine:latest
    name: main
  initContainers:
  - command:
    - init
    - the
    - database
    image: alpine:latest
    name: database-init
```

Comment: Maaaaany thanks! Works perfectly now. Nevertheless, it's surprising that such a simple thing cannot be done with the JSONpatches.